# Lower bound on the probability that a random variable is greater than half of its mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, information-theory

Consider a random variable $X$ that takes values between $-1$ and $1$. What is a non-trivial lower bound on the probability that the outcome of $X$ is greater than half of its mean?

---

EDIT:

I am looking for a bound that is a function of the mean (and so would cover the case where the mean is positive).

I.e.

$\text{Pr} \left[ X > {\mathbb{E}[X]  \over 2} \right] \geq f(\mathbb{E}[X]).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu=E[X]$  and $Z = \mathbb{1}_{X > \mu/2} $  (indicator variable), $a=P(Z=1)$

We are seeking for the maximal $g(\mu)$  such that $a \ge g(\mu)$

If $\mu < 0 $ then we cannot do better than the trivial $g(\mu)=0$.

(That can be seen by considering a Dirac delta on $x=\mu$)

For $\mu >0$:

$$
 \mu = E[E[X | Z]]= a E[X| Z=1]  + (1-a) E[X|Z=0] \tag1
$$

but $E[X| Z=1] \le 1$ (because $X\le 1$) and $E[X|Z=0] \le \mu/ 2$. Hence

$$ \mu \le a + (1-a) \mu /2  \implies a \ge  \frac{\mu}{2-\mu} \tag2$$

This bound is attained
by two Dirac deltas on $x=\mu/2$ and $x=1$ with weights $a$ and $1-a$ resp. 
Hence he desired bound is 
$$g(\mu)=\begin{cases}
0 & \mu\le 0\\
\frac{\mu}{2-\mu}  & \mu>0
\end{cases}\tag3$$

Answer (score 2):

For this distribution the mean is near $-1$, so half the mean is $-1/2$, and clearly the probability of finding $x>-1/2$ can be made arbitrarily small.

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you, but is there an expression for the lower bound as a function of the mean (which would cover the cases in which the mean is positive)?

Comment: That wasn't your question.  Please edit accordingly.

Comment: Please check the edited question.